# Why trigger works only once?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create query that after delete will insert data in other table. But I've deleted 3 rows in my table, but table with insert has only one row. And it's the first row that was deleted.

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE trigger trigger1 
ON Sales.SalesPerson
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID int

    SELECT @ID = BusinessEntityID FROM deleted

    INSERT INTO dbo.Deleted(ID)
    VALUES (@ID)

    PRINT 'TRIGGER'
END
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/) & [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, triggers fire *per operation*, not *per row*.

If you delete three rows, your `SELECT` assignment is going to (at least *logically*) assign each of those three values to the variable one at a time, and so the value that ultimately ends up in your logging table is the arbitrary value that happened to be assigned last.

You can simulate this as follows:

```
DECLARE @id int;
SELECT @id = database_id FROM sys.databases;
PRINT @id;
```

There are multiple rows in `sys.databases`, why did only one value get printed?

Instead of using a scalar variable and expecting it to somehow hold multiple values (or for the insert to happen multiple times), you need to insert as a set in a single operation:

```
INSERT dbo.Deleted(ID) 
  SELECT BusinessEntityID from deleted;
```

[Further reading](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/).